# Separate numpy 2-dimension array to two 2-dimension array

Tags: python, numpy

I merged 2 dimension array.

```
print(L.shape) #(89, 88201)
print(R.shape) #(89, 88201)
C = np.append(L,R,axis=1)
print(C.shape) #(178, 88201)
```

Now, want to separate the array `C`
to `(89, 88201)` as before.

How can I make it???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
L = C[0:89, :]
R = C[89:, :]
```